# Curly braces in asana math

Tags: math-mode, fonts, asana

I am having a readability problem with curly braces in math mode using Asana Math. Consider this snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
\[
  \{ x \mid x < 5 \}
\]
\end{document}
```

With Asana, the braces are somewhat too thin:

[image: Using Asana]

In particular, I find it hard to distinguish them from vertical bars at a small font size.
With the default font, the braces are somewhat "more curly":

[image: default]

Is this a setting or do I have to either change the glyphs or live with it?

Answer (score 2):

The basic shape of curly braces is determined by the font designer.

To improve the formula's legibility ever so slightly, you could follow the practice advocated by Knuth in the TeXbook (bottom of p. 174, in Chapter 18, "Fine Points of Mathematics Typing") and insert thinspace (`\,`) immediately after opening curly brace and immediately before the closing curly brace.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\begin{document}
$\{ \, x\mid x<5 \, \}$ vs.\ $\{ x\mid x<5 \}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree. thinspace is the right way to go

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different math font for the braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
\[
  \{ x \mid x < 5 \} \biggl\{\biggr\}
\]
\setmathfont[range={\lbrace,\rbrace}]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\[
  \{ x \mid x < 5 \} \biggl\{\biggr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Of course the `\setmathfont[range={\lbrace,\rbrace}]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}` declaration should go in the preamble, I used here just to show the difference.

[image]